# Proving that an improper Riemann integral involving $f(x)$ exists given that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable and periodic with period $1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

> Given that $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable and periodic with period $1$
>   and  $\int_{0}^{1}f\left(x\right)dx=0$, prove that
>   $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^{s}}dx$$ exists for $s>0$

Here's my attempt to prove it for $s>1$, Define a sequence {$a_n$} by $$ {a_n}=\int_{1}^{n}\left|\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^{s}}\right|dx$$

Using the fact that $f(x)$ is bounded, we have $$\int_{1}^{n}\left|\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^{s}}\right|dx\ \le\ M\ \int_{1}^{n}\frac{1}{x^{s}}dx=M\left(\frac{1}{s-1}-\frac{1}{\left(s-1\right)n^{s-1}}\right)<\frac{M}{s-1}$$ for all $n$. So {$a_n$} is an increasing sequence bounded above and therefore converges which implies that {$b_n$}= $\int_{1}^{n}\frac{f\left(x\right)}{x^{s}}dx$ also converges. Is this correct? and even if it is, this argument can't be applied when $0<s\le1$.

Comment: what you did is correct, however for $s\in(0,1]$ you cannot use the absolute value of $f$. For the latter I think you can use integration by parts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\int_1^{x} f(t) dt$. Then is also periodic with period $1$. Now $\int_1^{n} \frac {f(x)} {x^{s}} dx=\frac {g(x)} {x^{s}}|_1^{n}+s\int_1^{n} \frac {g(x)} {x^{s+1}} dx$. Note that $g(1)=g(n)=0$ so the first term vanishes. Now note that $g$ is bounded and repeat your argument with $g$ in place of $f$. Since we have $s+1$ in place of $f$ now your argument works fine now.

Comment: Why is $g$ bounded? what if $f(x)$ is continuous almost everywhere and not just continuous? how can we prove that $g$ is bounded then?

Comment: $g$ is continuous even if $f$ is not. Also $g(x+1)-g(x)=\int_x^{x+1} f(t) dt=\int_0^{1} f(t) dt=0$ by periodicity of $f$. Hence $g$ also has period $1$ which implies that $g$ is bounded. @Km356

Comment: We use continuity of $f$ to deduce continuity of $g$, but what if $f$ is continuous on $[0.1]$ except for a (possibly infinite) set of measure $0$, $f$ will be composed of infinitely many pieces that are continuous and we can deduce the continuity of $g$ except for a set of measure zero, how can we prove boundedness in this setting?

Comment: @Km356 You don't need continuity of $f$ to prove continuity of $g$. For any integrable function  $f$ (integrable either in Riemann sense or in  Lebesgue sense) the indefinite integral is always continuous.

Comment: @Km356 $|g(b)-g(a)|=|\int_a^{b} f(t)dt| \leq |b-a|M$ where $M$ is a bound for $|f|$. Hence $g$ is continuous. So you don't need continuity of $f$, just a  bound for $|f|$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:Apply Dirichlet's integral test.